# How to calculate rank from list of integer?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, ranking, rank

In database(SQL Server), say, one column values are like:

```
Col1
====
10
5
15
20
5
10
2
```

This is like list of integer data.

Rank should be:

```
Col1 Rank
==== ====
20    1
15    2
10    3
10    3
5     4
5     4
2     5
```

I have tried in following manner:

```
1) First sort the list of data in descending order of "Col1" value
2) Find the index of a particular record using FindIndex() method.
3) Then Rank = Index + 1
```

But it will only work if the data are unique. It fails when same "Col1" values are present in multiple rows as the index is returning `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6`.

How to calculate the rank when the list contains data which are not distinct(in most cases!) using C# LINQ?

Comment: what if taking distinct values first and then do the above scenario...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not do it in the database?

```
SELECT [Col1], DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Col1 DESC) AS [Rank]
FROM Table
```

But if you must do it in C#

```
var data = new List<int>();
var rankings = data.OrderByDescending(x => x)
                   .GroupBy(x => x)
                   .SelectMany((g, i) =>
                       g.Select(e => new { Col1 = e, Rank = i + 1 }))
                   .ToList();
```

Comment: This is wrong. `dense_rank()` should be used. The C# code is also wrong.

Comment: I believe the question says rank = index + 1

Comment: C# is still wrong. Rank must repeat for same-valued values, and only increase when the next value is lower.

Comment: I'll fix it in a second.

Comment: Thanks @Romoku for your help. This worked for me. Only .OrderByDescending(x => x) was missing.

Comment: @Romoku Can we do this without creating an anonymous  object... this creates a lot of performance issues list is longer..?

Comment: Yeah replace the anonymous object with your class.

Comment: Yes this is what I am doing. I have a class defined but still it takes much time... :(

Comment: What is the size of the list?

Comment: Around 900... Looking for an alternative way.. It would be good if we can have LINQ to Entity query equivalent for : SELECT [Col1], DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Col1 DESC) AS [Rank]
FROM Table

Comment: I doubt there is a performance issue (benchmarked it at a little over 3 seconds at 10k iterations with 900 random non-distinct integers between 1 and 900) with the linq query unless the query is being used with LINQ to SQL then your mileage may vary. You can use the standard ADO.NET with a stored procedure if it's that much of a performance issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you would do it in the database (either by running a query or by selecting from a VIEW), the query/view should be thus:

```
SELECT [Col1], DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Col1 DESC) AS [Rank]
FROM OriginalTable
```

This is much easier and faster than doing it in C# or any other language that must first retrieve the data and then post-process it.

Comment: If the question is "How do I do this using C# LINQ?", then how is your answer appropriate? Also: how do you know your SQL solution is faster... have you run tests versus a C# solution? If so, please post your numbers.

Comment: Any calculation that SQL Server can do for you will run faster than when you first fetch the data, then perform the calculation on that data. This is because SQL Server can optimize the way it fetches data and its calculation engine is optimized for speed. This is not just the case in an obvious example such as this, but also when it comes to having calculated columns in VIEWs. Yes, I have run tests, many years ago, and we even did very complex computations in SQL Server.

Comment: And how is the answer appropriate? Because the OP may be unaware that doing a calculation in SQL Server is a viable option.

Answer (score 1):

In C#:

```
var data = new List<int> { 10, 12, 7, 8, 7, 6, 3, 3, 4 };
var rankings = data.OrderByDescending(x => x).GroupBy(x => x)
                   .SelectMany((g, i) =>
                       g.Select(e => new { Col1 = e, Rank = i + 1 }))
                   .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var persons = Predictions
    .OrderByDescending(s => s.Points)
    .GroupBy(g => .Points)
    .SelectMany((g, i) => g.Select(s => new{ Rank = i + 1,s.Player,s.Points}).ToList());
```